# strange behavior of customized JPanel inside a JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I am new to `JTable`.

I made my own custom Renderer and Editor with JPanel. However, whenever I try to edit CustomJPanel, the table cell become blank.

Second thing is, the button on the bottom is intended to show controls (slider and button inside JPanel) for second row only. But it turned out to be showing all JPanel's controls.

My complete code is as follow:

**CustomJTableTest.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class CustomJTableTest extends JPanel
{

  TableModel customRendererEditorTableModel = new TableModel();
  JTable table;

  public CustomJTableTest()
  {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    table = new JTable(customRendererEditorTableModel);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.setRowHeight(300);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new CustomJPanelRendererEditor());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new CustomJPanelRendererEditor());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane);

    JButton showControl = new JButton("Show Second Row Controls");
    showControl.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
    TableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = (CustomJPanelRendererEditor) table.getCellRenderer(1, 1);
    java.awt.Component component = table.prepareRenderer(tableCellRenderer, 1, 1);
    if (component instanceof CustomJPanel)
    {
      CustomJPanel customJPanel = (CustomJPanel) component;
      customJPanel.setControlsVisible(true);
    }
      }
    });
    add(new JScrollPane(showControl), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom JPanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComponent newContentPane = new CustomJTableTest();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
    createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**CustomJPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CustomJPanel extends JPanel
{
  JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JButton jButton = new JButton("Button inside CustomPanel");
  JSlider jSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL);

  public CustomJPanel()
  {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(new Dimension(5, 300));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(jSlider, BorderLayout.EAST);

    jSlider.setVisible(false);
    jButton.setVisible(false);
  }

  public void setControlsVisible(boolean visible)
  {
    jSlider.setVisible(visible);
    jButton.setVisible(visible);

    repaint();
    revalidate();
  }
}
```

**CustomerJPanelRendererEditor.java**

```
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class CustomJPanelRendererEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor
  {
    CustomJPanel customJPanel = new CustomJPanel();

    @Override
    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
    {
      return customJPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public java.awt.Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {
      return customJPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() 
    {
        return null;
    }
  }
```

**TableModel.java**

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{

  private String[] columnNames =
  {
    "First Column",
    "Custom JPanel",
  };
  private Object[][] data =
  {
    {"Foo", new CustomJPanel()},
    {"Bar", new CustomJPanel()}
  };

  public int getColumnCount()
  {
    return columnNames.length;
  }

  public int getRowCount()
  {
    return data.length;
  }

  public String getColumnName(int col)
  {
    return columnNames[col];
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
  {
    return data[row][col];
  }

  public Class getColumnClass(int c)
  {
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
  {
    return col >= 1;
  }

  public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
  {
    data[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
  }

}
```

Anyone have a clue of what's wrong?

Thank you. Sorry for my english.

**UPDATE :**

I am stupid.I changed

```
TableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = (CustomJPanelRendererEditor) table.getCellRenderer(1, 1);
java.awt.Component component = table.prepareRenderer(tableCellRenderer, 1, 1);
```

to

```
TableCellEditor tableCellEditor = (CustomJPanelRendererEditor) table.getCellEditor(1, 1);
java.awt.Component component = table.prepareEditor(tableCellEditor, 1, 1);
```

in **CustomJTableTest.java**. The slider and button are now working. See [GIF](http://gfycat.com/DisloyalSandyKudu#?format=gif).
Now my problem is that CustomJPanel only show up when I click on that cell. And how do I turn on visibility of button and slider for particular cell only ?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried displaying CustomJPanel on its own?

Comment: @OliverWatkins yes it does show up

Comment: remove the 'extends AbstractCellEditor' part, and 'getTableCellEditorComponent' part. Does it show something different?

Comment: @OliverWatkins sorry for late reply. I removed `Editor` part. The panel was shown but it wasn't editable/accessible.

Comment: So it shows with just the renderer? try a seperate CustomJPanel object for each renderer and editor part. Ie. the getRenderer and getEditor methods shouldn't return the same instance, but two different instances.

Comment: dear @OliverWatkins I managed to make some progress. Can you please check on my **UPDATE** ? Thank you

Comment: and I've seperated renderer and editor as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to solve it. Thank you @Oliver Watkins for your kind help.

As summary to my fix, I added
`rendererJPanel = (CustomJPanel) value;` for both **getTableCellRendererComponent()** and **getTableCellEditorComponent()**

Comple code :

**CustomJTableTest.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class CustomJTableTest extends JPanel
{

  TableModel customRendererEditorTableModel = new TableModel();
  JTable table;

  public CustomJTableTest()
  {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    table = new JTable(customRendererEditorTableModel);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.setRowHeight(300);
    table.getColumn("Custom JPanel").setCellRenderer(new CustomJPanelRenderer());
    table.getColumn("Custom JPanel").setCellEditor(new CustomJPanelEditor());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane);

    JButton showControl = new JButton("Show Controls");
    showControl.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      { 
    // row 2
    TableCellEditor tableCellEditor = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).getCellEditor();
    java.awt.Component component = table.prepareEditor(tableCellEditor, 1, 1);
    if (component instanceof CustomJPanel)
    {
      CustomJPanel customJPanel = (CustomJPanel) component;
      customJPanel.setControlsVisible(true);
    }

    // row 1
    java.awt.Component component2 = table.prepareEditor(tableCellEditor, 0, 1);
    if (component2 instanceof CustomJPanel)
    {
      CustomJPanel customJPanel = (CustomJPanel) component2;
      customJPanel.setControlsVisible(true);
    }

    customRendererEditorTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
      }
    });
    add(new JScrollPane(showControl), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom JPanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComponent newContentPane = new CustomJTableTest();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
    createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**CustomJPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomJPanel extends JPanel
{

  JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JButton jButton = new JButton("Change Color");
  JSlider jSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL);

  public CustomJPanel()
  {
    jButton.setOpaque(true);
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(4);

    switch (randomInt)
    {
      case (0):
        colorPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        break;
      case (1):
        colorPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        break;
      case (2):
        colorPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        break;
      default:
        colorPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        break;
    }
      }
    });
    jSlider.setOpaque(true);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(jSlider, BorderLayout.EAST);

    jSlider.setVisible(false);
    jButton.setVisible(false);
  }

  public void setControlsVisible(boolean visible)
  {
    jSlider.setVisible(visible);
    jButton.setVisible(visible);
  }
}
```

**CustomerJPanelRenderer**

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class CustomJPanelRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
  {

    CustomJPanel rendererJPanel;

  public CustomJPanelRenderer()
  {
    rendererJPanel = new CustomJPanel();
  }


    @Override
    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
    {
      rendererJPanel = (CustomJPanel) value;
      return rendererJPanel;
    }
  }
```

**CustomJPanelEditor.java**

```
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class CustomJPanelEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor
{
  CustomJPanel customJPanel;

  public CustomJPanelEditor()
  {
    customJPanel = new CustomJPanel();
  }

  @Override
  public java.awt.Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
  {
    customJPanel = (CustomJPanel) value;
    return customJPanel;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getCellEditorValue()
  {
    return customJPanel;
  }
}
```

**TableModel.java**

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{

  private String[] columnNames =
  {
    "First Column",
    "Custom JPanel",
  };
  private Object[][] data =
  {
    {"Foo", new CustomJPanel()},
    {"Bar", new CustomJPanel()}
  };

  public int getColumnCount()
  {
    return columnNames.length;
  }

  public int getRowCount()
  {
    return data.length;
  }

  public String getColumnName(int col)
  {
    return columnNames[col];
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
  {
    return data[row][col];
  }

  public Class getColumnClass(int c)
  {
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
  {
    return col >= 1;
  }

  public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
  {
    data[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
  }

}
```